# Convergence of uncountable sum implies that index set is countable

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Definition: Let $I$ be a set and $a:I \to (0, \infty), k \to a_k$
> a map. W define convergence as follows:
>
> The series $\sum \limits_{k \in I} a_k$ is convergent if there exists
> $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum \limits_{j \in J} a_j \leq C$ for
> all finite sets $J \subset I$.

> Theorem: If $\sum \limits_{k \in I} a_k$ converges, then $I$ is
> countable.

Proof idea:

Let $S_n=\{i \in I:a_i>\frac{1}{n}\}$. I claim that $S_n$ is finite for all $n$.

To show this assume $S_n$ is infinite, then it is at least countable. Let $K \in S_n$ be a countable subset of $S_n$, then there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $K$ and we can define the series $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ (Note: The order of summation does not matter since all terms are positive).

Recall that $a_k>\frac{1}{n}$ for all elements of the series, and hence

$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k>\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}=\infty$

So $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ diverges because the series with terms $b_k=\frac{1}{n}$ diverges (use the comparison test). This implies that for all $M>0$, there exists an $N$ such that $m \geq N \implies \sum \limits_{k=1}^{m} a_k>M$, which contradicts our assumption that the uncountable sum converges.

Finally note that $I= \bigcup \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N} } S_n$ is a countable union of finite sets, so it must be countable.

Is my proof idea correct?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I am not sure what tags are appropriate for this question, so please feel free to add any.

Comment: The sum (seventh line) diverges because the terms do not tend to 0, not because the Harmonic series diverges. This is the only flaw I see upon my cursory reading.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks, that works as well. But can't we also use the comparison test with the harmonic series, which diverges?

Comment: OK, yes... ${}$

Comment: Actually, you could just omit that infinite sum and just say $\sum_{k=1}^{2Mn} 1/n=2M$.

Comment: David's comments are all you need--no harmonic series.  But write it up stressing the *finite set* part of the definition.  E.g,. If  $I$ is uncountable there is a positive $\epsilon_0>0$ so that $I_0=\{k\in I: a_k>\epsilon_0\}$ is infinite.   But then there can be no upper bound for $\sum_{k\in S} a_k$ for finite subsets $S\subset I_0$.  The real theorem here is this:  *If $f:I\to \mathbb R$ and $\sum_{i\in I}f(i)$ converges then the set $\{i\in I:  f(i)\not = 0\}$ is countable.*  Part of the theory of unordered sums.

Comment: P.S.  By the way $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1n = \frac1n+ \frac1n+\frac1n + \dots $ is very much *not* a harmonic series.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Oh yes, I confused $n$ and $k$, but the series still diverges.